# Proof limit value with $\epsilon/ \delta$

Tags: analysis, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

I have to find the limit value for $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ for $x \rightarrow0$. And then show with $\epsilon /\delta$ that I have found the right limit value.
I have found the limit value to $\sqrt{1+x} \rightarrow1$ for $x \rightarrow0$, by:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sqrt{1+x}
=\sqrt{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1+x)}=\sqrt{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1)+\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}(x)}=\sqrt{1+\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}(x)}=1$$

But I got a problem when I have to show it by $\epsilon /\delta$. When I write:
$$|f(x)-1|\Rightarrow|\sqrt{1+x}-1|$$
I can't see what I can use as a bound easier to find a $\delta$. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

What you need is essentially the continuity of the function $y\mapsto\sqrt{y}$ at $y=1$.

So you need an estimate
$$
|\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{1}|<\epsilon
$$

But observe that
$$
|\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{1}|=\frac{|y-1|}{\sqrt{y}+1}\le |y-1|
$$

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an instance of the 'multiplying by 1' trick:

Let $\epsilon > 0$, $\delta := \epsilon$. Then, for $x$ such that $|x|<\delta$ we have:

$$|f(x) - 1| = |\sqrt{x+1} - 1| = |\frac{(\sqrt{x+1}-1)(\sqrt{x+1}+1)}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}| = |\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}| \leq |x| < \delta = \epsilon $$